# long assembly code problem

Tags: assembly

I have a programm in assembly but when i add some lines of code it gets confused.
for example when i add a new procedure while this procedure works, the whole programm stucks at some point like it doesn't complete the procedure but stays in a specific point.the same happens when i add some commands that doesn't affect the programm, like some mov [300h],00h at the beggining of the code.

any idea how i can resolve this?
i have read that jmp command can only jump 128 addresses range. is that true? can i bypass this?
i have seen that some procedures has a "near" extension. like

- test proc **near**
- mov al,[0300h]
- ...
- ret
- test endp

what's that about? can that help me? thnx!

Answer (score 1):

First, `mov [300h],00h` is't something that won't affect the program. It could very well modify your code, so don't do this!

Second, only conditional jumps (Jcc) have this restriction for -128..+127 address range, so if you think that the branch is too far, then instead of

```
JE some_far_label
```

use

```
JNE skip1
jmp some_far_label
skip1:
```

And if you have some other questions, then please post some code.

EDIT: `mov byte [300h], 0` could overwrite your code. If you're using an assembler, then alloc explecitely space for variables:

```
var1 db 0
```

Comment: thanx a lot.
is there any reference that i could read more info about that kind of occasions? 
for example how mov [300h],00h affect my code?